# fast way to compare rows in a dataset

Tags: perl

I asked this question in R and got a lot of answers, but all of them crash my 4Gb Ram computer after a few hours running or they take a very long time to finish. 
[faster way to compare rows in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720488/faster-way-to-compare-rows-in-a-data-frame)

Some people said that it's not a job to be done in R. As I don't know C and I'm a little bit fluent in Perl, I'll ask here.

I'd like to know if there is a fast way to compare each row of a large dataset with the other rows, identifying the rows with a specific degree of homology. Let's say for the simple example below that I want homology >= 3.

```
data:
sample_1,10,11,10,13
sample_2,10,11,10,14
sample_3,10,10,8,12
sample_4,10,11,10,13
sample_5,13,13,10,13
```

The output should be something like:

```
output
   sample    duplicate    matches
1 sample_1   sample_2     3
2 sample_1   sample_4     4
3 sample_2   sample_4     3
```

Comment: Perhaps try [`Tie::Array::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3A%3AArray%3A%3ACSV)

Comment: It's taking me more than 30 minutes to write a script so not bothering :)

Comment: Is order important? For example 10,11,10,13 and 11,11,10,13 should return 3 matches or 0 matches?

Comment: That should return 3 matches.

Comment: how many matches would be for `10,11,12,13` and `8,9,10,11`?

Comment: That would be 0 matches.

Answer (score 1):

This solution provides an alternative to direct comparison, which will be slow for large data amounts. 
Basic idea is to build an inverted index while reading the data.
This makes comparison faster if there are a lot of different values per column.
For each row, you look up the index and count the matches - this way you only consider the samples where this value actually occurs.
You might still have a memory problem because the index gets as large as your data.
To overcome that, you can shorten the sample name and use a persistent index (using `DB_File`, for example).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @h;

my $LIMIT_HOMOLOGY = 3;

while(my $line = <>) {
    my @arr = split /,/, $line;

    my $sample_no = shift @arr;
    my %sim;
    foreach my $i (0..$#arr) {
        my $value = $arr[$i];
        our $l;
        *l = \$h[$i]->{$value};
        foreach my $s (@$l) {
           $sim{$s}++;
        }
        push @$l, $sample_no;
    }
    foreach my $s (keys %sim) {
        if ($sim{$s}>=$LIMIT_HOMOLOGY) {
            say "$sample_no: $s. Matches: $sim{$s}";
        }
    }
}
```

For 25000 rows with 26 columns with random integer values between 1 and 100, the program took 69 seconds on my mac book air to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Matches are calculated when both lines have same numbers on same positions,

```
perl -F',' -lane'
  $k = shift @F;
  for my $kk (@o) {
    $m = grep { $h{$kk}[$_] == $F[$_] } 0 .. $#F;
    $m >=3 or next;
    print ++$i, " $kk  $k  $m";
  }
  push @o, $k;
  $h{$k} = [ @F ];
' file
```

output,

```
1 sample_1  sample_2  3
2 sample_1  sample_4  4
3 sample_2  sample_4  3
```

Comment: Simply Superb! use of `grep` in `map` format amazed me! Learning from your solutions.

Comment: @jkshah I'm glad you find it useful :)

Comment: Can you please benchmark your code with bigger input sizes? He's got input data with 26 columns and 250,000 rows. I've benchmarked up to 25,000 rows in [my Rcpp solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19730940/1412059) and would be interested in seeing the performance in perl.

Comment: @Roland I would but don't have your input file and I'm not familiar with R/Rcpp. For some quick results you can check `date; perl ...; date`

Comment: @mpapec I'm not familiar with perl.

Comment: @Roland it is a matter of copy/paste in command line. Chances are you already have perl installed.