# Find pairwise matches between two datasets by row (every cell)

Tags: r, compare

I have two tables (females and males) with presence-absence data and I'd like to do pairwise comparisons between them (row-by-row) to find the number of cells shared by each pair (cell content = 1 in both) .

I've seen similar questions here in SO, but most try to find the differences of full row content (not cell-by-cell). I believe what I need is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720488/faster-way-to-compare-rows-in-a-data-frame) but wasn't able to implement it with my specific case.

Here is an example (although I actually have .csv tables from Excel)

```
females <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=T))
males <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1), nrow=5, byrow=T))
rownames(females) <-c ("female_1","female_2","female_3","female_4","female_5")
rownames(males) <-c ("male_1","male_2","male_3","male_4","male_5")
```

My ultimate goal is to have a new dataset with females on the rows and males on the columns with the number of shared cells between every pair possible (I think I can get this part done with reshape once I figure out the other part).

```
           male_1 male_2 male_3 male_4 male_5
female_1      2      2      1      2      1
.
.
.
.
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crossproduct of the two matrices is what you want... Or maybe it is the dot-product, whatever it is called this should do it:

```
as.matrix(females) %*% t(as.matrix(males))



        male_1 male_2 male_3 male_4 male_5
female_1      2      2      1      2      1
female_2      1      2      0      2      0
female_3      2      1      3      2      3
female_4      3      3      2      4      2
female_5      3      2      3      3      3
```

Comment: Also, there's a helper function `tcrossprod(as.matrix(females), as.matrix(males))`

Comment: Thanks a lot emilliman5 and Frank! I'm getting this message "requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments". Could this be because I'm importing a .csv file with headers?

Comment: All I can say is that the data needs to be numeric and a matrix. Check the class of an individual cell (should be "numeric") and the class of the entire object (should be "matrix"). `read.csv` produces a data.frame, which if everything is numeric in the data.frame then `as.matrix` should suffice