# How to calculate matching objects without removing NA or 0

Tags: r

I have an output for example as below:

```
ID C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
1  0  1  2  2  1  1
2  0  1  1  2  1  1
3  1  0  1  1  1  1
4  2  0  2  2  1  2
5  2  1  1  0  2  2
6  1  2  1  0  1  2
7  2  2  2  2  0  2
8  1  1  1  1  0  1
9  1  1  2  2  2  0
10 1  2  1  2  1  0
```

and I determine the co-occurrence of objects through example from [faster way to compare rows in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720488/faster-way-to-compare-rows-in-a-data-frame?rq=1)

```
for ( i in 1:(nr-1)) {
# all combinations of i with i+1 to nr
samplematch <- cbind(dt[i],dt[(i+1):nr])

# renaming the comparison sample columns
setnames(samplematch,append(colnames(dt),paste0(colnames(dt),"2")))

#calculating number of matches
samplematch[,noofmatches := 0]

for (j in 1:nc){
samplematch[,noofmatches := noofmatches+1*(get(paste0("CC",j)) == get(paste0("CC",j,"2")))]
  }

# removing individual value columns and matches < 5
samplematch <- samplematch[noofmatches >= 5,list(ID,ID2,noofmatches)]

# adding to the list
totalmatches[[i]] <- samplematch
}
```

The result obtains through above function help me identify the total matching between each ID. However, i only to identify the matching ID when the CC(1:6) consist only value 1 and 2. Meaning that the total value for each row suppose to be 5 and not 6.

The output that i require should consist information such as

```
ID1 ID2 Match
1    2   4/5
1    3   2/5
1    4   3/5
:    :    :
:    :    :
2    3   3/5
2    4   2/5
```

How should the function be written without remove any rows since each rows has value 0.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, `IDs` is a data table of all pairs of distinct `ID`s. Then you need to check `x <- df[c(ID1, ID2), -1]`, the non-ID columns of `df` corresponding to the given `ID` pair, for each row. The code creates a logical vector which is `TRUE` for non-zero columns (`x[1] != 0`) and columns with equal elements (`x[2] == x[1]`). The sum of this vector is then the number of matches.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setkey(df, ID)

IDs <- CJ(ID1 = df$ID, ID2 = df$ID)[ID1 != ID2]
IDs[, Match := {x <- df[c(ID1, ID2), -1] 
                sum(x[1] != 0 & x[2] == x[1])} 
    , by = .(ID1, ID2)]

head(IDs)
#    ID1 ID2 Match
# 1:   1   2     4
# 2:   1   3     2
# 3:   1   4     3
# 4:   1   5     1
# 5:   1   6     1
# 6:   1   7     2
```

Data used:

```
df <- fread('
ID C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
1  0  1  2  2  1  1
2  0  1  1  2  1  1
3  1  0  1  1  1  1
4  2  0  2  2  1  2
5  2  1  1  0  2  2
6  1  2  1  0  1  2
7  2  2  2  2  0  2
8  1  1  1  1  0  1
9  1  1  2  2  2  0
10 1  2  1  2  1  0
')
```

Comment: I have run it on 200 sample and the running time take approximately 1.5 mins. is there any alternative to write a function for more than 400 sample.. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @IceCream. the match result is obtain from the function is what i needed. I have another query. If my ID is not arrange in ascending order, how am I going to retain the the ID as it is. For example, If the ID is arrange as (35,28,75,162,107)